# Storing column value types to an array

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to refactor my code. I create a fix column so I always write "table.columns.Add(name, dataType) ...."´.

I want to keep it with a loop and store all these column informations into an two dimensional array.

The first value of this array is the column name, the second is the type of the column.

How can I store this type?

My current code:

```
 object[,] tableColumns = { // Contains all column names + column dataType
            {"Predecessors", List<Process>},
            {"Successors", List<Process>},
            {"ProcessId", int},
            {"ProcessName", string},
            {"ProcessDuration", int},
            {"FAZ", int},
            {"SAZ", int},
            {"FEZ", int},
            {"SEZ", int},
            {"EntireBuffer", int},
            {"FreeBuffer", int},
            {"IsCritical", bool},
            {"IsStartProcess", bool},
            {"IsEndProcess", bool}
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < tableColumns.Length; i++) // create all these columns
        {
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add(tableColumns[i, 1].ToString(), tableColumns[i, 2] as Type);
        }
```

So as you can see, the only thing missing here is the storing of the datatype in its correct way.

Comment: typeof(): `typeof(int)`, `typeof(bool)`, etc. Btw, do you create a new DataTable or adding column to an existing one? if it is new there is a way to use collection initializer for Columns

Comment: oh cool thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var tableColumns = new Dictionary<string, Type>{ // Contains all column names + column dataType
        {"Predecessors", typeof( List<Process>)},
        {"Successors", typeof(List<Process>)},
        {"ProcessId", typeof(int)},
        {"ProcessName", typeof(string)},
        {"ProcessDuration", typeof(int)},
        {"FAZ", typeof(int)},
        {"SAZ", typeof(int)},
        {"FEZ", typeof(int)},
        {"SEZ", typeof(int)},
        {"EntireBuffer", typeof(int)},
        {"FreeBuffer", typeof(int)},
        {"IsCritical", typeof(bool)},
        {"IsStartProcess",  typeof(bool)},
        {"IsEndProcess",  typeof(bool)}
    };

  for (int i = 0; i < tableColumns.Length; i++) // create all these columns
  {
    ProcessTable.Columns.Add(tableColumns[i, 1].ToString(), tableColumns[i, 2]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For storing the actual type of an object, C# uses the `Type` class. You can get the respective Type object for any class, struct, etc. via the `typeof(*classname*)` operator.

If you want to get the `Type` object from an actual object, you can use the object's `GetType()` method.